# How to ignore parent of a nested json value if it doesn't exist, in python?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to extract the value `y` that sometimes is nested and sometimes is not. I use code like this:

```
address = response.json()[x][y]
```

I also use a ternary operation on x like:

```
address = response.json()[x if condition else ""][y]
```

It works when `y` is a nested value of `x`, but when it's not I get the error `KeyError: ''`.
I also tried `None` instead of `""`, but still the same error `KeyError: None`.
Also have tried this:

```
address = response.json()[x] if condition else ""[y]
```

I'd like to keep it compact if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `response.json()` is it a dict ?

Comment: `data = response.json()` `address = data[x][y] if condition else data[y]`

Comment: you have  `data[y]` but you try to get `data[""][y]` or `data[None][y]` - it doesn't work this way.

Comment: @furas Thank you, I now see my error. So is there no way to make it completely ignore the first brackets (x) if it's empty?

Answer (score 2):

*Safe* and short way with `dict.get(key[, default])` function:

```
data = response.json()
address = data.get('y') or data.get('x', {}).get('y')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm gonna go with @furas' answer because it's compact and besides I don't know how to do ternary operation in your method. I get `None` when I try it.

Answer (score 1):

Not best code, but should afford your problem

```
try:
    address = response.json()[x][y]
except:
    address = response.json()[y]
```

Comment: Would be better with `except KeyError`, since you shouldn't catch all the exceptions, except if you really know what you're doing (and this is not useful here)